# Dark Mode XML (Night) on jetpack compose android studio missing

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I only have 1 Theme file in values. and I want to change the status bar when in dark mode to different color. but no clue where to do it since i only know how when there are 2 files

Comment: why don't you create a second file?

Comment: how to add a second file that also switches depending on color theme

Answer (score 4):

The solution to the status bar color problem :

1 - go to the website and do all first three steps:
the link: https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started

I used this version: 1.7.0-beta01

2 - go to the themes.xml and change the parent to
"Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"

3 - do the same images here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9wC0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcYGy.png)

Comment: Best answer on the whole internet. Thank you.